# Mathematica taking very long time to solve DE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Is it normal that Mathematica takes more than 2 hours to solve this system of differential equations?

**ODEs:**

```
OdeM = 1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - em*V1[x] == -((2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep));
OdeP = 1/2*\[Sigma]X^2*V2''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V2'[x] - ep*V2[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep));
```

**Initial conditions:**

```
Ic1 = em*V1[xhat] + ep*V2[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = em*V1'[xhat] + ep*V2'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = V1[xhat] + V2[xhat] == (2*\[Theta])/((\[Epsilon] - 1) (1 + \[CurlyPhi]))*xhat;
Ic4 = V1'[xhat] + V2'[xhat] == (2*\[Theta])/((\[Epsilon] - 1) (1 + \[CurlyPhi]));
```

**Solver:**

```
Sol = DSolveValue[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {V1[x], V2[x]}, x] //FullSimplify
```

The same system without the four initial conditions takes barely any time. I am afraid I am doing something wrong, even though it seems a pretty standard problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The same system without the four initial conditions takes barely any
> time.

It has nothing to do with IC. It is `FullSimplify` which takes very long time.  Try

```
Timing[DSolveValue[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {V1[x], V2[x]},x]]
```

On my PC, V 13.2.1 it takes 4.5 seconds

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I renamed your σX^2  to $w$. As I mentioned in your other question [wrong-sign-in-variation-of-parameters-method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284002/wrong-sign-in-variation-of-parameters-method) , it is bad idea to use two letters for one variable. Why do you insist in using σX  for a variable instead of say `w` or any other single letter?

Any way, it is well known that `FullSimplify` can slow things alot as it tries many types of simplifications. Try to use it only if needed. `Simplify` is much faster than `FullSimplify`

### Full code

```
OdeM = 1/2*w^2*V1''[x] + ((a0*δ)/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] == -((2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)*λ)/(em - ep));
OdeP = 1/2*w^2*V2''[x] + ((a0*δ)/a1 - a1*x)*V2'[x] - 
    ep*V2[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)*λ)/(em - ep));

Ic1 = em*V1[xhat] + ep*V2[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = em*V1'[xhat] + ep*V2'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = V1[xhat] + V2[xhat] == (2*θ)/((ϵ - 1) (1 + φ))*xhat;
Ic4 = V1'[xhat] + V2'[xhat] == (2*θ)/((ϵ - 1) (1 + φ));
Timing[DSolveValue[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {V1[x], V2[x]}, x]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I used FullSimplify because I was hoping to find in a clear way what the four constants are.

Answer (score 3):

```
gensol = DSolve[{odeM, odeP(*,ic1,ic2,ic3,ic4*)}, {V1, V2}, x];

linsys = 
 CoefficientArrays[{ic1, ic2, ic3, ic4} /. Equal -> Subtract /. 
   First@gensol, Array[C, 4]]
paramsol = Thread[Array[C, 4] -> LinearSolve @@ Reverse[{-1, 1} linsys]];
icsol = gensol /. paramsol
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{ic1, ic2, ic3, ic4} /. icsol // Simplify
```

> ```
> {{True, True, True, True}}  *)
> ```

Comment: This is not running for me

Comment: @NC520 I changed the initial upper case to lower case (following best practices). Except I forgot to do it for `V1` and `V2`. Or: I forgot to change a sign (now fiexed). Otherwise, you'll have to be clearer. It works for me.

Comment: It works now. Thank you.